# Documentation for react-sigma-v2 or just sigmajs

Tags: sigma.js

I was wondering if there is any decent documentation for specifically react-sigma-v2 or just sigma.js. There are handful of examples but even those have limitations on how much it can show/how you can adapt it to your project. Aside from the github and [this page](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/main/README.md) are there any other resources that anyone can recommend to gain a better understanding of sigma.js in general?